# Adding eventListeners in a loop (mouseenter) but only triggering after 1500ms - issue with clearTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout, addeventlistener, nodelist, cleartimeout

I have a grid of images, which users can mouseover to preview. I am able to add a listener to each one in a loop. I would only like to trigger my logic if the user is over the item for at least 1.5 seconds. I can't determine why  my mouseleave event which attempts to clearTimeout of the timer, is not actually clearing it.

I have added comments in the code to also clarify:

```
(function () {
  var nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('div.MyDiv > img') || undefined;
  if (nodeList) {
    nodeList.forEach(function (_el, idx) {
      _el.addEventListener("mouseenter", function (e) {
        var _imgsrcga = e.srcElement.src;
         var timer = setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('This ran'); // this is OK after 1.5 seconds, but it ALWAYS runs after 1.5 seconds
        }, 1500)
      }, false);

      // not clearing the timer....
      _el.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(e) {
        console.log('cleared')
        clearTimeout(timer) // my timer never clears with a mouseleave event
      })
    })
  }
})();
```

So: my console.log('this ran') does in fact delay 1.5 seconds, but I can never get rid of my timer if they mouseleave in < 1.5 seconds.

Thanks

Comment: Declare `timer` in the outer function (IIFE). The second event handler cannot see the variable and fails silently.

Comment: Yes, @RandyCasburn is right. You should learn more about the [scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

Comment: You might also consider using a delegated event handler, and a `WeakMap` to store the timer references for each element so you don't have to add an event listener to every single element.

Comment: Oh right, while JS reaches into the outer scope, it will not reach into the scope of the addEventListener callback. Given that I need access to properties available in the event object of addEventListener, I probably need to change my general approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the timer outside the function in order to be accesible from other functions.

```js
(function () {
  var timer;
  var nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('div.MyDiv > img') || undefined;
  if (nodeList) {
    nodeList.forEach(function (_el, idx) {
      _el.addEventListener("mouseenter", function (e) {
        var _imgsrcga = e.srcElement.src;
         timer = setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('This ran'); 
        }, 1500)
      }, false);

      _el.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(e) {
        console.log('cleared')
        clearTimeout(timer)
      })
    })
  }
})();
```

```html
<div class="MyDiv">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300">
</div>
```

I include the way i would write this piece of code. In my opinion, your code could be structured differently, for the sake of readability & understanding. I've removed some unnecessary lines too, and used ES6 syntax.

```js
(function () {
  let timer;
  let nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('div.MyDiv > img');

  const mouseOver = e=> {
    let _imgsrcga = e.target.src;
    timer = setTimeout( ()=> console.log('This ran'), 1500)
  };
  const mouseOut = e=> {
    console.log('cleared')
    clearTimeout(timer)
  };
    
  nodeList.forEach( _el=>{
    _el.addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver , false);
    _el.addEventListener("mouseout", mouseOut);
  });
  
})();
```

```html
<div class="MyDiv">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300">
</div>
```

Notes :

- use `mouseover` and `mouseout` events instead
- don't use e.srcElement, use e.target (standard)
- don't need to check nodeList after querySelectionAll (worst case, you'll have an empty list, and forEach will do nothing)
- don't declare inline event handlers (better performance)

Comment: Thanks for the bullets. "This ran" never runs, "cleared" runs immediately on mouseleave. No real changes to your code other then my nodelist declaration.

Comment: In my implementation i used 'mouseover' and 'mouseout' events, which work as expected

Comment: You're right, my  situation had an edge case. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

variable "timer" is not visible in cleaning function. It is private variable for "mouseenter" event function.